# Matplotlib: How to reduce the number of axis labels to make it more legible?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I wrote the following code to create a graph in matplotlib:

```
plt.plot(batches, meanCell)
plt.show()
```

The problem I am having is that there are hundreds of pieces of data and it looks like it is trying to put every single piece of data in the axis of the graph:
[image]

How would I go about formatting the axis to put less labels so the numbers are legible?

Comment: What have you tried? It's considered reasonable for you to have had an attempt, and shown it here, before asking for help

Comment: Don't use strings if you want to plot numbers.